# Dynamically adding columns to a pyplot not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

Not really a pressing issue but it's bugging me: I want to display several images side by side (i.e. several columns) but for some reason the following code (taken from [python tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html)) only displays the images in one column. So what I want is a layout like this

```
X X X
```

but what I get is

```
X
X
X
```

code:

```
...
plt.ion() 
...
fig = plt.figure()
sample = face_dataset[65]       # <== this is a simple image of size 640x480
for i, tsfrm in enumerate([scale, crop, composed]):
    transformed_sample = tsfrm(sample)

    ax = plt.subplot(1, 3, i + 1)
    plt.tight_layout()
    ax.set_title(type(tsfrm).__name__)
    show_landmarks(**transformed_sample)
plt.show()
...
```

Here is the show_landmarks function definition:

```
def show_landmarks(image, landmarks):
    """Show image with landmarks"""
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.scatter(landmarks[:, 0], landmarks[:, 1], s=10, marker='.', c='r')
    plt.pause(0.001)  # pause a bit so that plots are updated
```

I do not think the different transforms (scale,crop, composed) matter so I left them out but they can be found under the link above.

If I write basically the same as a test code the columns show up fine:

```
fig = plt.figure()
for i in (0,1,2):
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 3, i + 1)
    plt.tight_layout()
    ax.set_title(i)
plt.show()
```

So my guess is that somehow show_landmarks messes things up. Can anybody point me in the right direction as to why/how that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `show_landmarks` so it is making calls to the current plotting axis, rather than to `plt`.  Then pass the axis to the function as well as the other args.

```py
def show_landmarks(ax, image, landmarks):
    """Show image with landmarks"""
    ax.imshow(image)
    ax.scatter(landmarks[:, 0], landmarks[:, 1], s=10, marker='.', c='r')

...
for i, tsfrm in enumerate([scale, crop, composed]):
    transformed_sample = tsfrm(sample)

    ax = plt.subplot(1, 3, i + 1)
    ax.set_title(type(tsfrm).__name__)
    show_landmarks(ax, **transformed_sample)

plt.tight_layout()
...
```